# VirtualBox 4.3.2 - Bidirectional Drag & Drop Enabled, but only Host to Guest Works

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, windows-8.1

I would like to use virtual box for bidirectional file transfer with my 64 bit Ubuntu 13.10 virtual machine. I have enabled it in the settings, but so far, I have only managed to transfer from host to guest. Whenever I try to transfer from guest to host, the icon on the guest simply moves to the edge of the screen, and the drop does not occur. My host is Windows 8.1 Pro. Does anyone know what my problem is, or am I not doing something correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The help file says Drag'n'Drop is **only** implemented for Linux guests and **only** for copying files from the **host to the guest.** It seems that the drop down lists more options than are currently supported.

[image: Drag'n'Drop content]

Footnote 12 [reads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCi7Y.png): `Support for Drag'n'Drop was added with VirtualBox 4.2`
but this only refers to the partial support as indicated above. Prior to 4.2 there was no Drag'n'Drop support, nor menu.

Comment: Support for Drag'n'Drop was added with VirtualBox 4.2. It even says so in your post.